# Delphi Pointers, Arrays, Handles

Tags: delphi, pointers, enums, delphi-xe4, window-handles

I can't get my head around pointers using a custom record and making array of records then a pointer to that record, specifically what I want to achieve is to make a record for each top level window handle with the given classname, meaning there is more than 1, for each window I use `EnumChildWindow` to obtain handles to child windows with in. I wanted to make record of each of these and pass it to a combobox with title and make the record an object of that item so I can access each recorded later on via selecting it.

My problem is my handling of pointers, I keep getting access denied on the first instance of adding any to one of the array records.

Breaks here

```
Param[Form1.iEnumWin].MainHwnd:= aHwnd;
```

here is the full code I am using so people can get a better understanding on what I am trying to do.

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}
type
  TMyEnumParam = record
   sTitle: String;
   MainHwnd: Hwnd;
   InTxtHwnd: Hwnd;
   OutTxtHwnd: Hwnd;
   NickListHwnd: Hwnd;
end;
 PMyEnumParam = ^TMyEnumParam;

 type
 ATMyEnumParam = Array[0..9] of PMyEnumParam;
 PATMyEnumParam = ^ATMyEnumParam;

{ Get the window Title based on Hwnd }
function GetWindowTitle(HWND: HWND): string;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 255);
  SetLength(Result, GetWindowText(HWND, PChar(Result), 255));
end;

{ Get the Classname based on Hwnd }
function GetWindowClass(HWND: HWND): string;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 255);
  SetLength(Result, GetClassName(HWND, PChar(Result), 255));
end;

{ EnumChildWidows Callback Add to our records }
Function EnumChildProc(aHwnd: Hwnd; Param: PMyEnumParam): Boolean; stdcall;
begin
     if ((GetDlgCtrlID(aHwnd) = 202) and (isWindowVisible(aHwnd) = True)) then
      Param.InTxtHwnd:= aHwnd;

     if ((GetDlgCtrlID(aHwnd) = 203) and (isWindowVisible(aHwnd) = True)) then
       Param.OutTxtHwnd:= aHwnd;

     if ((GetDlgCtrlID(aHwnd) = 1789) and (isWindowVisible(aHwnd) = True)) then
      Param.NickListHwnd:= aHwnd;

      Result:= True;
end;

{ EnumWindow fill our array of records for each window }
function EnumWindowsProc(aHwnd: HWND; Param: PATMyEnumParam): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  Result := True;
  if GetWindowClass(aHwnd) = 'DlgGroupChat Window Class' then
  begin
   Param[Form1.iEnumWin].MainHwnd:= aHwnd;
   Param[Form1.iEnumWin].sTitle:=  GetWindowTitle(aHwnd);
   EnumChildWindows(aHwnd, @EnumChildProc, LParam(@Param[Form1.iEnumWin]));
   Form1.cbbRooms.AddItem(Param[Form1.iEnumWin].sTitle, TObject(Param[form1.iEnumWin]));
   inc(Form1.iEnumWin);
  end;
end;

{ On change display room Title for each item }
procedure TForm1.cbbRoomsChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  aHwnd: PMyEnumParam;
begin
  i := cbbRooms.ItemIndex;
  if cbbRooms.ItemIndex <> -1 then
  begin
    aHwnd:=  PMyEnumParam(cbbRooms.Items.Objects[i]);
    if aHwnd.MainHwnd > 0 then
    begin
     ShowMessage(aHwnd.sTitle);
    end;
  end;

end;

{ Call EnumWindows and fill our array records }
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
 arInfo: PATMyEnumParam;
begin
  iEnumWin:= 0;
  EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsProc, LParam(@arInfo));
end;
```

Please if anyone can point (no pun intended) me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Comment: A shameless plug, but if you are lost with pointers, you may want to read http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html . David already told you what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many things wrong with your code. Here's a non-exhaustive list:

1. You don't allocate any storage for your arrays.2
2. You pass `^PATMyEnumParam` to `EnumWindows` which you then cast to `PATMyEnumParam` in the callback.
3. Your arrays are fixed length and you make no attempt to handle out of bounds access to the arrays.

But your biggest problem is that your code is attempting to run before you can walk. It has full complexity and all the functionality that you need. Yet you cannot yet manage to make a single successful call to `EnumWindows`.

My biggest piece of advice here is not in the detail, but the generality of problem solving. Start by writing a simple piece of code. Understand it. Then enhance it.

So, in that vein, here is how to make a call to `EnumerateWindows`:

```
program EnumWindowsDemo_17620346;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, Winapi.Windows, Generics.Collections;

type
  TWindowInfo = record
    Handle: HWND;
    // expand with more fields in due course
  end;

function EnumWindowProc(hwnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  WindowList: TList<TWindowInfo>;
  WindowInfo: TWindowInfo;
begin
  WindowList := TList<TWindowInfo>(lParam);
  WindowInfo.Handle := hwnd;
  WindowList.Add(WindowInfo);
  Result := True;
end;

procedure Main;
var
  WindowList: TList<TWindowInfo>;
  WindowInfo: TWindowInfo;
begin
  WindowList := TList<TWindowInfo>.Create;
  try
    EnumWindows(@EnumWindowProc, LPARAM(WindowList));
    for WindowInfo in WindowList do
      Writeln(WindowInfo.Handle);
  finally
    WindowList.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  Main;
  Readln;
end.
```

Starting from here you can expand this concept, because all the tricky parts are already taken care of. Specifically the pointer, casting and memory management.

Comment: Thank you I do appreciate it, I know what I want to do but as you said pointers and memory management is my failer, I normally try and keep away from these and use Delphi in such a way that it is handled for me, Being a hobbyist only programmer I still have much to learn when dealing with memory, I have dealt with EnumWindow and EnumChildWindows before without issues and not passing parameters for it to use, so no real memory management required.. Thanks again, I will work on this, and now seeing how you have use TList to assign a record makes it even more interesting.

Comment: The big benefit of TList<T> is that you don't have to worry about memory allocation